# Python асинхронные циклы

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, многопоточность, asyncio

Можете расписать как запускать циклы асинхронно? Не понимаю немного доки

Дано:

```
def mus():
    while True:
def dis(arg1, arg2):
    while True:
```

Хочу что бы они не останавливали друг друга тк один рисует текст, а другой принимает текст/нажатие кнопок/думает и работает с переменными которые улетают первому что бы он рисовал уже новые данные.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте переменные которые `mus` будет менять, а `dis` использовать. Аргументы не годятся - они не меняются во времени. Без этих подробностей вопрос закроют как неясный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дизайн выглядит непродуманным, нужно больше подробностей как `dis` будет получать обновления. Сейчас он получает аргументы на старте и нигде не сказано, как они могут меняться.

Ниже код который запустит `mus` и `dis` параллельно. Основная техника: насоздавать нитей, запустить их, ждать их окончания. В нашем примере они не кончаются, но ждать надо - программа завершается когда завершается основная нить. Пример мог бы быть проще: две нити - излишество, можно было обойтись одной. Да я хочу показать технику вообще, кроме того хорошая практика не занимать основную нить - позже для неё обязательно найдется "работа по дому":

```
import threading
import time


def mus():
    while True:
        print('mus')
        time.sleep(0.9)


def dis(arg1, arg2):
    while True:
        print('dis({}, {})'.format(repr(arg1), repr(arg2)))
        time.sleep(1.5)


def test(arg1, arg2):
    threads = (
        threading.Thread(target=mus),
        threading.Thread(target=dis, args=(arg1, arg2))
    )

    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    print('started')

    for t in threads:
        t.join()


test('arg1', 'arg2')
```

Заметьте где печатается `started`. Добро пожаловать в мир параллельного программирования:

> ```
> mus
> dis('arg1', 'arg2')
> started
> mus
> dis('arg1', 'arg2')
> mus
> mus
> dis('arg1', 'arg2')
> mus
> dis('arg1', 'arg2')
> mus
> mus
> dis('arg1', 'arg2')
> mus
> mus
> dis('arg1', 'arg2')
> mus
> dis('arg1', 'arg2')
> mus
> ...
> ```

Comment: Всё это хорошо, но вопрос был вроде бы про асинхронность, а не про многопоточность. (Это немного разное всё-таки.)

Comment: @CrazyElf, если речь про один поток, то вам надо придумывать искусственный планировщик, и фактически изобретать велосипед.

Comment: @CrazyElf асинхронность не всегда асинкио. Вопрос в исключении блокировок по большей части